# If a, b, c are three linearly independent vectors show that the vectors a × b, b × c, c × a are also linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

> If $a$, $b$, $c$ are three linearly independent vectors show that the vectors $a \times b$, $b \times c$, $c \times a$ are also linearly independent.

I have tried proving with three linearly independent vectors and working out the determinants of the cross products, but I cannot seem to get them to equal 0.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that
$$\lambda(a\times b)+\mu(b\times c)+\nu(c\times a)=\vec 0\ .$$
Taking the scalar product with $c$ gives
$$\lambda\>(a\times b)\cdot c=0\ .$$
Since the triple product is assumed $\ne0$ it follows that $\lambda=0$, and similarly for $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Comment: To prove that if three vectors a,b,c are linearly independent, then it must satisfy  $a\cdot(b\times c)=0$?

Comment: @sawankumawat : Three vectors $a$, $b$, $c\in{\mathbb R}^3$ are linearly independent **iff** $a\cdot(b\times c)\ne0$.

Answer (score 2):

You are given that $$a\cdot b\times c=\Delta\neq0$$
and you need to show that $$(a\times b)\cdot((b\times c)\times(c\times a))\neq0$$

Writing, for convenience, $n=c\times a$, we can evaluate the inner bracket  $$(b\times c)\times n=c(n\cdot b)-b(n\cdot c)$$ using the BACCAB rule. Then simplifying further, we get $$(b\times c)\times n=c[(c\times a\cdot b)-b(0)]$$

Therefore, $$(a\times b)\cdot((b\times c)\times(c\times a))=(a\times b)\cdot c(c\times a\cdot b)=\Delta^2\neq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** It's enough (in fact, equivalent) to show that the triple product
$$\newcommand{\bfa}{{\bf a}}\newcommand{\bfb}{{\bf b}}\newcommand{\bfc}{{\bf c}} \newcommand{\bfx}{{\bf x}}\newcommand{\bfy}{{\bf y}}\newcommand{\bfz}{{\bf z}}[(\bfa \times \bfb) \times (\bfb \times \bfc)] \cdot (\bfc \times \bfa)$$ of $\bfa \times \bfb, \bfb \times \bfc, \bfc \times \bfa$ is nonzero.

We can rewrite this quantity using the occasionally useful cross product identity
$$
(\bfx \times \bfy) \times (\bfx \times \bfz) = (\bfx \cdot(\bfy \times \bfz)) \bfx .
$$

> Substituting gives that the triple product is $$(\bfa \cdot (\bfb \times \bfc))^2,$$ but this is just the square of the triple product of the original vectors $\bfa, \bfb, \bfc$; since the set of these vectors is linearly independent, this latter triple product is nonzero.